# How to get more location data within 20 second duration by requesting to NETWORK_PROVIDER?

Tags: android, networking, gps, location, locationmanager

Hi I have used the below code to get the location information from the network provider.

```
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                mLocationUpdatePendingIntent);
```

After 20 second I removed the location update. But with in 20 second am getting only 2 location data. Even connected with WiFi I am getting only 2 location data. If connected to WiFi I am getting the better accuracy location data. But still 2 location data.

I tried Location Request With GPS_PROVIDER, I am getting around 30 different location data.

Location request With NETWORK_PROVIDER in sony mobile with Aircel sim, I am not getting any location data in 20 seconds duration.

And also Location request With NETWORK_PROVIDER in samsung mobile with Airtel am getting only 2 samples in 20 seconds duration.

Location request With PASSIVE_PROVIDER never returns me any location data. I have used the Google Map apps. Still passive provider returns nothing.

I don't want to use the Fused location api. I need to use the Location manager. So How to get more location data with the help of NETWORK_PROVIDER. And also in sony mobile I am not getting any location data when requesting location with NETWORK_PROVIDER.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Have a look at [Get *coarse* location from GPS provider on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460888/get-coarse-location-from-gps-provider-on-android): "Other providers will still return location results, but the update rate will be throttled", "To meet the privacy expectations of users when your app requests permission for coarse location (and not fine location), the system will not provide a user location estimate that’s more accurate than a city block."

Comment: @Uber Lem Thanks for your reply. Even outside and also in city block am getting only 2 location data within 20 second duration. I given both the permissions FINE and COARSE.

Comment: why do you need more updates? network provider accuracy is around 30 meters with the best scenario (usually worse). Are you sure you need it more often?

Comment: Every update i will get the different accuracy right. It's like accuracy 30, 29, 30, 28 and so on. So finally I will get the best accuracy data.