# Does the GPS provider require the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission or not?

Tags: android, gps, location, android-maps

This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460888/get-coarse-location-from-gps-provider-on-android) thread seems to indicate that it does but the links to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) in the same thread says:

> Unless otherwise noted, all Location API methods require the Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permissions. If your application only has the coarse permission then providers will still return location results, but the exact location will be obfuscated to a coarse level of accuracy.

Which makes me think that Google added coarse location support for the GPS provider. However, I am getting this error:

`Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: "gps" location provider requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.`

Of course the best way forward would be to use the [fused location provider API](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current) but until then I think the documentation should be clearer about this? Mostly looking for an updated answer.

Comment: There is no question in your post.

Comment: I think the title is pretty clear: Does the GPS provider require the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission or not?

Answer (score 2):

ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION includes permission only for NETWORK_PROVIDER Not GPS.

Got to know more on this from the comments on this [StackOverflow Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35869610/13533028)

There seems to be a switch from the MarshmallowVersion. Pre Marshmallow the CoarseLocation let you use the Gps but obfuscate the location for privacy

Comment: "In the case of LocationManager, you can only use the `NETWORK_PROVIDER`". Does this mean the documentation is wrong in saying that "**providers** will still return location results, but the exact location will be obfuscated to a coarse level of accuracy"?

Comment: That works pre marshmallow. I think that part of the documentation is not mentioned, You can check the StackOverflow like for more reality.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is Yes.
To be complete, starting from API31 the use of the GPS provider requires both `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permissions.
On lower APIs the GPS provider requires only the `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission.